# Uploading file in selenium webdriver to html label (mac)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate an image upload using selenium webdriver with java. The problem is that rather than the html element of the link to upload being an 
, it's a label: (without the spaces in tags so it shows)

`< label class="btn btn-default btn-icon btn-blue custom-file-upload ng-binding" for="logo">Select file< /label>`

This prevents me from using sendKeys with the absolute path which is usually the simplest method: 

`@FindBy(xpath="//label[@for='imageUpload']") private WebElement imageUploadLabel;
imageUploadLabel.sendKeys("AbsolutePathHere");`

I've tried using robot/action class as well as there are many examples on these forums of that but as soon as the browse file upload window pops up it effectively kills my script. I know the best way to do this would be just to change the html element in the source code but that is not an option, so I'm looking for another way to possibly do it.

I'm using a mac as well so autoit is not an option. I've looked extensively on these forums and others trying to find an alternative but every option I've encountered either uses an input file html element or does not work for me. Let me know if more information is needed. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In mark up it has to be <input type='file'> , I could assume that it is hidden somewhere or it is dynamically created when you click on label

Comment: It has to be <input type='file'> to upload any file at all or with webdriver? The label opens the os file upload popup window when clicked.

Comment: Never faced such a situation, but a quick fix could be using `Robot` class along with `java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard` to contain the path and provide it to the pop-up. Though a warning: Robot class has its own cons... :|

Comment: It should be at all as I know <input type='file'> is only the one way how to implement file upload